# React - how to optimistically set local state whilst waiting for the api call to confirm the save result?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two radio buttons and when I click one of them I want the state of the UI to change immediately, then make a call to save this change in the backend, then if a failure in the backend occurs revert the UI.

Here is the React component:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

  handleModeChange(event) {
    const { saveFeatureActivationMode } = this.props;
    const {target} = event;
    const selectedMode = target.value;
    const { currentMode } = this.state;
  
    this.setState(
      {
        currentMode: selectedMode
      },
      () => saveMode(
        selectedMode,
        () => revertMode(currentMode),
      )
     );
  }

  revertMode(currentMode) {
    this.setState({ currentMode })
  }
  ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    saveMode: (mode, onError) =>
        dispatch(updateMode(mode, onError)),
});
```

Then my updateMode action creator is:

```
const updateMode = (mode, onError) => ({
    type: SEND,
    payload: {
        url: `/api/update/mode`,
        options: {
            body: {
                mode,
            },
            method: 'PUT',
        },
        onSuccess: () => (
            showNotification("Success!");
        ),
        onError: () => {
            onError();
            return showGlobalError("Error occurred!");
        },
    },
});
```

Note that the `SEND` action type will be picked up by some redux middleware and will actually send the api request.

Now, I can see immediately that this design breaks two rules of redux, 1) one-way flow, 2) passing non-serialisable functions into an action creator. How else would it be best to optimistically set the UI the when the mode is changed, but revert upon failure?

Comment: One way to handle this would be to use a custom hook for handling API actions instead of your middleware, but I'm not sure if you're looking to change your code that much.

Comment: Another way is to build your store state in a way such that you store information about a pending request alongside each entity.  With this approach you would handle everything in your redux state through middleware, sagas, etc.  When dispatching the "start" action you would store the pending changes.  On success you move them from pending into the entity's actual data.  On failure you would remove them from pending.  Your selector would look for pending changes and apply them overriding the current.  I'm not sure if I'm explaining this well so maybe I'll code that as an answer.

Comment: As an alternative to putting the pending changes in the state, your middleware could select the current value and keep it as a local variable and then dispatch a change action that would change it back to that value on failure.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of ideas on how you could handle this, in terms of hook-based approaches, determining what logic is passed into the hook via props and what logic is innate to the hook's functionality depends on what the use cases are in your app where you could reuse this logic.

What I came up with here is a hook that handles the "pendingness" of any value which is updated through the API and then stored in redux.

### useOpportunisticValue

#### Arguments

- **`mapStateToValue`** `(state) => value` a redux selector which selects the current value from the state.
- **`publishChanges`** `(pendingValue) => Promise<newValue>` an async function which calls the API and returns the new value that was set in your backend.  You could ignore the fetched response and return the same value, but returning a value here allows this to support cases where the API performs some sort of normalization such that the pending value and new value aren't exactly the same.
- **`dispatchChanges`** `(dispatch, value) => void`  a callback which gives you access to the new value and `dispatch` such that you can call dispatch with the appropriate action.

#### Returns

`[value, onChange]` a tuple in the style of `setState`

- **`value`** the value which should be displayed in your component, allowing your component to be agnostic about whether the value is pending or permanent.
- **`onChange`** `(newValue) => void` a callback to call when you want to update the value.

This hook extracts out the logic of determining which value is the current one.  Calling `onChange` will cause `value` to change immediately, but the `value` might later revert back if the API update fails.

#### Code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const useOpportunisticValue = (
  mapStateToValue,
  publishChanges,
  dispatchChanges
) => {
  // state stores the pending value when changes are pending
  // or null at all other times
  const [pendingValue, setPendingValue] = useState(null);

  // select current value from redux store
  const storedValue = useSelector(mapStateToValue);

  // the value returned to the component is the pending value when changes are pending
  // or the value from redux otherwise
  const value = pendingValue === null ? storedValue : pendingValue;

  // onChange handler returned to the component updates the pending value
  const onChange = (value) => {
    setPendingValue(value);
    //TODO: cancel subscriptions to previous updates
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // hook listens for changes to the pending value
  useEffect(
    () => {
      // this value is used to prevent error "called setState on an unmounted component"
      // if the component using this hook unmounts before the API returns
      let isSubscribed = true;

      const execute = async () => {
        // only do anything if we have an actual value
        if (pendingValue === null) return;
        try {
          // publish the changes to the API
          const newValue = await publishChanges(pendingValue);
          // only dispatch the changes to redux after API success
          dispatchChanges(dispatch, newValue);
        } catch (e) {
          // clear the pending changes in the case of a failure
          if (isSubscribed) {
            setPendingValue(null);
          }
        }
      };
      execute();

      // return cleanup function
      return () => {
        isSubscribed = false;
      };
    },
    // needs extra deps to pass eslint with exhaustive checks
    // I am leaving off publishChanges and dispatchChanges for no so that you don't have to memoize
    [pendingValue]
  );

  // return a [state, setState] tuple
  return [value, onChange];
};
```

#### Typescript Version

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { useDispatch, useSelector, DefaultRootState } from "react-redux";

const useOpportunisticValue = <T, State = DefaultRootState>(
  mapStateToValue: (state: State) => T,
  publishChanges: (value: T) => Promise<T>,
  dispatchChanges: (dispatch: Dispatch, value: T) => void
): [T, (value: T) => void] => {

  const [pendingValue, setPendingValue] = useState<T | null>(null);

...
```

#### Usage

Obviously you would want to extract some of the logic using selector functions, action creators, an API client, etc.

```
const Mode = () => {
  const [mode, onChange] = useOpportunisticValue(
    (state: MyState) => state.mode,
    async (mode) => {
      const res = await axios.request({
        url: `/api/update/mode`,
        data: { mode },
        method: 'PUT',
      });
      return res.data.mode;
    },
    (dispatch, mode) => dispatch({
      type: "SET_MODE",
      payload: mode
    })
  )

  // do some actual better rendering
  return (
    <div>Mode: {mode} </div>
  )
}
```